# libcurl and special characters conversion

Tags: c, http, libcurl

I'm using libcurl to provide HTTP GET and PUT requests
request contains login, password and some additional information.

Password contains @ symbol - 1qa@WS#ED
The query is created in the following way

```
snprintf(api_req, sizeof(api_req), "http://%s:%s@%s/export?uuid=%s",\
XEN.user_name,XEN.user_passwd, XEN.host_ip, BACKUP_TASK.vm_uuid)

http://root:1qa@WS#ED@192.168.1.1/export?uuid=4851501f-82d5-cb73-3158-175cffbbf848
```

Off course this request will fail as @ shoul be converted to %40, also for ':', dot, percent symbol etc
But this is OK password for any OS and user account.
What is the best way for handling such issues? Parsing string symbol per symbol with replacemnents seems not very effective.
I'm using plain C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**curl_easy_escape()**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html) to escape the characters on your password.

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't notice this function before. Works like a charm!